# Error when changing location of ofstream file C++

Tags: c++, windows, ofstream

I had code that looked like this:

```
std::vector <std::string> info;
info.push_back("10");
info.push_back("this is a line to print");
std::ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("list.txt");
myfile<<"first*"<<info[0]<<"\n";
```

which worked fine but when, it creates the file and prints the information, but when I changed it to this:

```
std::vector <std::string> info;
info.push_back("10");
info.push_back("this is a line to print");
std::ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("Output\\list.txt");
myfile<<"first*"<<info[0]<<"\n";
```

it creates the file but the instant I try to output to the file the whole thing crashes. I am using code::blocks with a GNU gcc compiler on windows 8.

Comment: what is "Output"? seems like you are using it as relative path. but is actually not.

Comment: Its a folder that I have enclosed in the folder the program is running in

Comment: `pushback` should be `push_back`. "\n should be "\n". I created a folder `Output` and copied your code to a file at the same level of `Output` directory, ran it, it worked fine. I can see `first*10` in the file `list.txt` under Output folder

Comment: right, sorry those are all just me typing it in wrong, thats right in the code but I will go ahead and fix that

Comment: i doubt, program just stores files in default folder, if no path is provided absolutely. so if you want the file to be written on the folder of your own choice, try providing the absolute path. eg: C:\doc\projects\abc\Output.

Comment: ok, i will try that out

Comment: now it doesn't even create the text file, that might have been me messing up so im checking that now

Comment: k I got it to start creating the file again but it still crashes before it manages to output the text

Comment: don't forget double slashed " \\ " . did you?

Comment: yes, it won't even compile if I don't add that

Comment: that's weird. i really tried it rite now, just to make myself clear. it worked fine at my side :|

Comment: its slightly different in my code, I didn't think it would make a difference, my code has a variable for the file name then inputs it as varname.c_str()

Comment: yea, you're right. it shouldn't make any difference at all.

Comment: wait, now its not working even when I use try to save it to the folder my program is in

Comment: you must be missing something, somewhere else. try to dry run, for tracing the mistake out.

Comment: ok so now it actually does go beyond the output statement but nothing that I output ends up being saved

Comment: its starting to look like this is actually a problem further in my code. I saw it make the file but not output and assumed that that was the problem but now that i'm adding print statements to debug it doesn't look like it is. Sorry about this!

Comment: yep, i have pinpointed the problem to a string transformation below the other code that is leading to the problem, sorry to have wasted your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

provide the absolute path as "C:\Documents\yourprojects\yourcurrentproject\Output\list.txt". and it will work fine. i tried it.

Comment: Using single backslashes, `\`, may cause problems with directory names. Prefer '/' (forward slash) instead.